# How to optimize drawImage source and destination coordinates to visible region of the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

In some exotic HTML5 Canvas implementations rendering an image with `drawImage()` to a small canvas but using a large scale factor cause massive memory consumption, crashes or rendering errors because the image is physically scaled up before drawing it into the canvas. The same happens when drawing the image with a large destination size (i.E. `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100000, 100000)`).

I'm searching for an implementation of a drawImage wrapper function which optimizes the source coordinates to the minimum needed rectangle and corrects the destination coordinates so the actual visual output is exactly the same as when using the original coordinates.

A simple example without any canvas transformations:

- Canvas size is 1000x1000
- Image size is 100x100
- Rendering the image with `drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100, 2000, 1000)` stretches the image horizontally onto the canvas so only the left half is visible.
- The wrapper function must optimize the parameters to this: `drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 100, 1000, 1000)` because only the left half of the image is relevant so only this part of the image must be rendered and the destination coordinates must be corrected accordingly.

This example is very easy to achieve but the wrapper function must take the current canvas transformation into account so it works with any source and destination coordinates and with any transformation which has been applied to the canvas before rendering the image.

Here is some template code for the function I am looking for:

```js
function drawImageOptimized(ctx, img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh) {
    const transform = ctx.getTransform();

    // Crop source coordinates to minimum needed rectangle within the
    // image by taking the canvas size and the current transformation
    // matrix into account.
    const sx2 = ...;
    const sy2 = ...;
    const sw2 = ...;
    const sh2 = ...;

    // Correct destination coordinates
    const dx2 = ...;
    const dy2 = ...;
    const dw2 = ...;
    const dh2 = ...;

    // Render minimal needed part of image
    ctx.drawImage(img, sx2, sy2, sw2, sh2, dx2, dy2, dw2, dh2);
}
```

Only the canvas size and the current canvas transformation matrix must be taken into account. Clipping paths can be ignored. Filters and Shadows which might work differently because of the changed coordinates are out of scope and can also be ignored.

How can this be implemented properly?

Comment: To get this "properly" is far from being trivial. One thing you have to take into consideration is that the context can have a clipped area. This means that you have to be able to compute the actual drawing area of any transformed path, overwrite all calls to `clip()` to catch these and add in a stack. I did this in [this project](https://github.com/Kaiido/CanvasLayer) which required that do to auto sizing of layers. To be able to do so, I needed to include [that other project of mine](https://github.com/Kaiido/path2D-inspection/), to be able to extract the Path2D details. Really, not trivial.

Comment: Clipping is irrelevant. Sorry, maybe the name drawClippedImage is confusing. I try to edit the question to make it more clear. Clipping paths can be completely ignored. Only the canvas size and the canvas transformation affects the output.

Comment: What about filters and shadow? These also apply on drawings that are outside of the visible clipping area (e.g `ctx.shadowOffsetX=350; ctx.drawImage(img, -350, 0, 500, 500)` should (normally) draw the shadow in the visible canvas.

Comment: Shadows are a good point. They won't work correctly. Maybe a different workaround for shadows is needed but it is out of scope here.

Comment: Well that's the point. You need to define your scope very precisely. Maybe it's just "how can I get the arguments to drawImage so that it fits in a given, possibly transformed, bounding box", but it needs to be clearly defined.